# How to call Add() on a List with an unknown name at compile time?

Tags: c#

How can I call `unknowList.AddRange(elements)` when the name isn't know?

I have the following code but `addMethod` is always null. Any ideas as to why?

```cs
public class Tree : Harvestable
{
}

public class JobManager
{
    List<Tree> treeSelections = new List<Tree>();


    public void OnMarkHarvestableSignal(List<Harvestable> selections)
    {
        string fieldName = selections[0].GetType()
                                        .ToString()
                                        .ToLower() + "Selections";
        FieldInfo field = this.GetType()
                              .GetField(fieldName, BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);

        if (field is null)
            throw new Exception($"Field {fieldName} not found");
        
        MethodInfo addMethod = field.GetType()
                                    .GetMethod("AddRange");
        addMethod.Invoke(field, new object[] {selections});
    }
}
```

Comment: Reflection is generally an antipattern. Are you using it because you think it’s the right choice, or would other ways of mapping a `Harvestable` to a corresponding list be helpful instead?

Comment: I'm not sure how else to do it. If you've got some other approaches I'd love to hear it

Comment: I don't understand this. How is it that `JobManager` is defined at compile time, but you have to resort to reflection to access the list? Also, it seems like you're trying to add a `List<Harvestable>` to your unknown list. Does that mean you have a `List<List<Harvestable>>` that you're looking for?

Comment: Could you provide the Harvestable class?

Comment: I'm wanting to take this path because otherwise, I have to have a ton of if statements for the various types that could inherit from Harvestable. Seems cleaner. There could be 20 different classes that inherit from Harvestable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could require `Harvestable` instances to identify themselves:

```
public abstract class Harvestable  // or however it’s actually defined
{
    public abstract Category Category { get; }
}
```

where `Category` could be an `enum` with an entry for each class, or `object`, or `string`, or some [custom symbol-like type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34371287/does-c-sharp-have-a-symbol-type).

Then `JobManager` maintains a dictionary of lists:

```
public class JobManager
{
    Dictionary<Category, List<Harvestable>> CategorySelections
        = new Dictionary<Category, List<Harvestable>>();

    public void OnMarkHarvestableSignal(List<Harvestable> selections)
    {
        CategorySelections[selections[0].Category].AddRange(selections);
    }
}
```

Comment: I like this, but I have a couple of questions. Wouldn't the dictionary need to be defined with all of the various enums? Why need an enum when you'd be able to grat the class type itself?

Comment: @TimO For one, improper use of reflection can move what would have been compile time errors to runtime errors that might not even be detected until a specific circumstances are reached (e.g. you have a type you add only very rarely). Another reason is that reflection is generally slower than directly writing the code you're trying to avoid. Of course the speed is relative and doesn't really make a noticeable difference in some situations.